# django tables2 display sort arrows on header

Tags: css, django, django-tables2

I'm using django tables2, and I think it would be useful to have up and down arrows on header columns to indicate the current sorting order, especially when the default sort is on a column other than the first.

Tried playing with CSS but no luck, any suggestions or examples on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482977/) may solve your problem, though it it hard to know for sure without knowing what you have tried already with CSS.

The [templates that come built-in](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-rendering.html) with django-tables2 all render column attributes to the final HTML, so that a column that is defined as `orderable=True` will produce column header tags with an `"orderable"` class (e.g. `<th class="orderable">`). Furthermore, columns that have been selected to sort ascending or descending will have `asc` or `desc` class identifiers added on render.

So, you can set up a CSS rule that will render three different arrow images depending on the state of the orderable column:

```
table.table thead th.orderable {
    background: url(path_to_unsorted_indicator_image)
}

table.table thead th.asc.orderable {
    background: url(path_to_ascending_indicator_image)
}

table.table thead th.desc.orderable {
    background: url(path_to_descending_indicator_image)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this answer, but prefer that the column header verbose name is closer to the text.  I added code to the Table **init**():

```
for i in range(len(self.columns)):
        if is_blank(self.columns[i].column.verbose_name):
            my_label = self.columns[i].name.replace("_", " ").strip()
        else:
            my_label = self.columns[i].column.verbose_name.strip()

        arrow = '&#x21f5;' if self.columns[i].orderable else ""

        self.columns[i].column.verbose_name = mark_safe(f'{my_label} {arrow}')
```

To capture a different icon to indicate sorting, I used Tables.before_render(). By looking at the request, the GET field has a dict with a key of "sort" and a value that is the field_name.  If it's a reverse sort, the field_name has a - prefix.

This seems a bit of a hack, but I can't find a better way.  The upshot is the column header can reflect the sort.